# Strange phenomenon: Java/Swing-operations cause access violation in native library (JNA)

Tags: java, swing, access-violation, jna

Greetings fellow developers!

Since SO was almost always helpful with my programming problems, I decided to sign up and give it a shot with my most recent problem. It really is a strange phenomenon that neither I nor my collegue can figure out. I'm sorry I can't provide a working sample, but the project is way to complex to break it down, and specific hardware is needed to run it properly. So I'll try my best to explain it.

The foundation of our project is a native library (a 32-Bit Windows C-DLL in this case) to access project-specific hardware via a Java application ([JNA](http://jna.java.net/)). The purpose is to manage and display the proprietary file-system of the hardware (connected via USB) in a Swing UI. This is a pretty common project configuration for us, since we integrated a lot of native libraries and drivers in Java applications.

**Summary:** Unit-tests for enumerating devices work fine. A module of the native library allocates memory and fills it with structs, each containing information for a connected device. It is not good practice, but since we do not have any influence on this part we have to go with it. I mapped this struct in Java/JNA, call the native function, copy the struct content to a Java transfer class and print it in the console. Works just fine.

Now if there are UI-operations active while enumerating devices, the native library crashes with an access violation. Even if this UI-operations have nothing to do with the library. The JNA error message shows an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), which SO research revealed as invalid/empty memory.

Has anyone ever encountered such problems before? We certainly never did. It took me days to narrow down the error source to this part of the code. Debugging is not easy when native libraries are involved.
Is it possible that there is a JVM memory concurrency problem? Since the native library allocates memory by itself and the JVM doesn't know anything about it - so the JVM tries to allocate memory for new Swing components in already used memory?

**Code:** 
The following snippet is from my unit-test, broken down as far as possible. The intended sequence is obvious: Remove nodes from the root-node, load connected devices and add these devices as new nodes. This code crashes with an access violation, but NOT AT THE NATIVE CALL - it crashes as soon as I access tree components.

```
    public void loadDevices(){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rootNode.removeAllChildren();
                rootNode.add(new LoadingNode());
                tree.expandPath(new TreePath(rootNode));
            }
        });

        final List<Device> devices = lib.loadDevices(); // wrapped native call

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rootNode.removeAllChildren();
                if(!devices.isEmpty()){
                    for (Device dev : devices ) {
                        DevNode node = new DevNode(dev);
                        rootNode.add(node);
                    }
                }
            }
         });
     }
```

Note: The *DevNode* does not contain any native data, the content of each native struct is copied to a Java transfer object. The GC should not have issues when trying to move object data, because all unmanaged code is handled locally in the *lib#loadDevices()* method.

When I remove the calls to the *SwingUtilities* completely and print the resulting device information to the console instead of creating nodes, this part works fine. 
As soon as I try to access the *JTree* or *TreeModel* members, the code crashes. It doesn't metter if I do this in a call to *SwingUtitilies#invokeLater()* or in the same thread.

I know this is a very specific problem that hardly anybody would be interested in (what makes it really hard to search for solutions in SO/Google). But maybe I am lucky and somebody has already encountered this problem.

So long
xander

**Edit:** Originally this code was wrapped in a worker thread, leading to the same results. This is just a snippet of my unit-test.

**Edit 2:** It seems I didn't make myself clear enough or forgot to mention something important here, sorry. The access to the tree or its model doesn't necessarily have to do with the native library. Look at the code again: The first call to invokeLater does nothing but remove nodes from the tree. Even when I remove the second call to invokeLater, the native library crashes!

Comment: Do you have by any chance listeners attached to the `JTree`/`TreeModel` which in turn trigger the native code ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! No, that's what I meant by "all unmanaged code is handled locally". There is no further access to the native library

Comment: And could you try to replace the `invokeLater` with an `invokeAndWait` call. Now you return from the `loadDevices` method without being sure that your tree is already in the correct state. Who knows what other code relies on that tree.

Comment: @Robin then make me sence if is about synchronizations multiple of threads, has nothing to do with returns from JNI/JNA

Comment: Though this is practically all code concerning the tree, I'll give it a try as soon as I have access to the hardware again. Assuming there is no further code relying on the tree: the calls to inokeLater should be executed chronologically by the SwingUtilities, right? I'll update my question, because it doesn't seem to be clear enough that the tree operations don't necessarily have to concern the native libary. But thanks again so far!

Comment: clear is that you aren't able to convert possible returns from JNI/JNA to local Java variable, you lost JNA or returns, really job for debugging on your local enviroment and/or/with System.out.println()

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry, I don't really understand your first statement here. How do I lose "JNA or returns"? This println()-debugging is inevitable when working with native libraries. That's how I narrowed the error source down to this part.

Comment: are you sure that you calling Object that exist in present time, if I understand, all native code doean't exists if value is returned

Comment: Does the exception happen within a Java stack trace or within a native thread (if the former you can at least convert it into a Java exception with `Native.setProtected(true)` for debugging purposes)?  That's a pretty standard null pointer dereference on windows.

Comment: @mKorbel: Yes, the calling object does exist at that time. The native data itself (i.e. the JNA mappings of the native data) should not exist any more, only its copied values.

Comment: @technomage: The access violation happens in a native thread as far as I understand it. I'll try to set the execution mode to 'protected'. I knew this feature existed, but in the first days of JNA it didn't work well, so it never occurred to me to use it again.  <br/>  Thanks so far, I'll test it and update you as soon as I have further information :)  EDIT: I don't seem to get the comment formatting, the <br/> doesn't add a new line but is displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have struggeled a lot with JTree untill I learned this:

On JTree one should not edit the nodes itself, but use the methods provided on the DefaultTreeModel:

```
setRoot(TreeNode root) 
removeNodeFromParent(MutableTreeNode node) 
insertNodeInto(MutableTreeNode newChild, MutableTreeNode parent, int index)
```

Editing the nodes itself can (and will sooner or later) lead to strange behaviour.

This ofcourse when you are using DefaultTreeModel and MutableTreeNode. I would strongly advise to do this as I have seen to many wrong implementations of TreeModel.

Comment: Thanks bluevoid, that's good to know. I am always using DefaultTreeModel and derived classes of DefaultMutableTreeNode when working with JTree, since I ran into trouble with other implementations before. Though I don't think that's the actual problem with the native library, I'll implement it as soon as I have time for this project and give it a shot!

Comment: This eventually solved my problem! And credits also go to @Robin, for pointing out to use SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait() instead of #invokeLater(). It bugs me that I still don't understand this strange behaviour of my software, since I wrote many many similar programs. But at least it works now, so thanks to all of you guys! I would like to upvote your comments/answers, but my reputation isn't high enough....

Answer (score 1):

```
final List<Device> devices = lib.loadDevices();
```

- (by assuming that your code by using JNA is able to returns each node separatelly or collection of `List<Device>'s` one time if ended) should be called from Worker Thread, e.g. Runnable#Thread or SwingWorker
- all output from to Worker Thread add to the DefaultTreeModel directly (or by creating a new MutableTreeNode) should be wrapped into invokeLater
- no idea whats happens withut posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (`List<Device>'s` could be list of USB ports), short, runnable, compilable, just about JTree, is Model, and JNI/JNA ...

Comment: I updated my question: The original code was in a worker thread, that's why the calls to invokeLater are there. The results were the same. Unfortunately I can't provide a SSCCE... Like I wrote - it needs specific hardware to run. That's why I didn't post this question earlier. But thanks for the fast response anyway!

Comment: Forgot something: Like mentioned in the question, *Device* is just a transfer class. It contains copied data from the native struct. It's my usual MO to prevent GC problems with unmanaged code. Is it in any way important, what this class does?

Comment: really I don't know, by default there isn't be issue, only access to the enviroment, now I don't know if native code running from JNI/JNA has the same authority to Windows resources, the same as logged user, have to test separatelly, at begining to run code from cmd